# Import WSDL with Java and maven without using deprecated libs

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to update the Java version of a Java project (using intellij as IDE).

So, I installed JDK 17 and I found out that wsimport was removed. But is there any solution/alternative that is not deprecated so I can import and generate java classes?

I also found that I can still use wsimport (only if I set as java path Java 8) and run the code with maven jaxws-rt, but that packages in 2022 also look like they're already deprecated too, because I can only use 2.x version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

there's already a "3.0.2" version, but if I update it i'll get a compilation error when I execute "mvn clean install":
package javax.jws does not exist

and the runtime error when I try to consume the service:
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:61) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]

the is my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <log4j.version>2.17.0</log4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>rm.ccr.JCCUI</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Copy project dependency -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jgoodies/jgoodies-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgoodies-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgoodies-forms</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

So, these are in reality two questions:

1- How can I generate wsdl java classes only with jdk17 and non-deprecated libs.

2- How can I consume SOAP services in java without deprecated libs?

Answer (score 1):

I was going through this same issue. So, I used cfx plugin to generate the class files from WSDL. After that I used maven-replacer-plugin to replace javax.xml.bind imports with jakarta.xml.bind.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>replace-for-jakarta</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesToInclude>target/generated-sources/**/*.java</filesToInclude>
                        <preserveDir>true</preserveDir>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>javax.xml.bind</token>
                                <value>jakarta.xml.bind</value>
                            </replacement>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>javax.xml.ws</token>
                                <value>jakarta.xml.ws</value>
                            </replacement>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>javax.jws</token>
                                <value>jakarta.jws</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```